# Linking object files with struct accesses compiled on architectures with different alignment restrictions

Tags: c, struct, compilation, linker

I was asked the following question and was stumped:

What happens when you try to link object files with struct accesses where the code has been compiled for the same architecture and instruction set, but with different alignment restrictions? The struct definition is the same.

I feel like the code couldn't be linked for several reasons:

1. Possible alignment restriction violation
2. One object files struct access would be at a different offset than the others

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few possibilities:

1. The harmless one:
   The different alignment-restrictions are benign in this case, they lead to the same final layout. All is good that ends good Depending on your types, not very unlikely.
2. The compiler saves such info and the mismatch is detected on linking.
   Unlikely, not sure of any compiler doing so.
3. The likely one.
   The code will be linked without warning or error, but will misbehave more or less spectacularly, due to different parts of the program having different ideas about how types are layed out.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest there would be profound and lovely errors, not necessarily at compile time, if the structs are saved to and from files.  *(Although individual structs can be forced to an alignment that is the same, despite compiler project settings (not easy though).)*  If the structs are not saved to and from files, and their sizeof is not used in any way across libraries - then the DLLs could fit together in some instances without a problem.  But with files this is a **big** problem, and will give bad behaviour.